# How to let underline fade in beneath link on hover?

Tags: html, css

How can I fade in an underline on hover over a link like in the video below?

[image: GIF]

I found this CSS by using the developer console, but I can't figure out how it works.

```
.mainContent p>a:hover::after, .mainContent li>a:hover::after, .mainContent .text a:hover::after, .mainContent p>a:focus::after, .mainContent li>a:focus::after, .mainContent .text a:focus::after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-2px);
    transform: translateY(-2px);
}
.mainContent p>a::after, .mainContent li>a::after, .mainContent .text a::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: rgba(226,0,26,1);
    content: '';
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s,-webkit-transform 0.2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.15s,-moz-transform 0.2s;
    transition: opacity 0.15s,transform 0.2s;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(4px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(4px);
    transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://www.google.de" target="_blank">Hallenplan</a>
```

How does this work and is there a even better way?

Comment: unfortunately you can't animate an underline on it's own as it would animate the text as well.  with the css you show, they make an `:after` pseudo element that is a line the size of the anchor and shift it to the bottom, then animate the opacity (as well as moving it upwards for some reason) - if you just want the opacity, remove all the `translateY`s from the hover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this effect you need two things:

- Give the `a` a `position` attribute
- Animate its `after` element by placing it at the bottom through `position: absolute` and then `transform`ing it.

One possible way is:

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover::after, a:focus::after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

a::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s, transform 0.2s;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">
    StackOverflow
</a>
```